# connect to (local) with different windows login

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-authentication

I have an odd scenario.

I inherited a box that has SQL Server 2008 R2 on it already. The previous user connected to the `(local)` database with Windows Authentication using their Windows login.

I have a different Windows login. Is there any way for me to be able to log into the `(local)` database? The old user is no longer around, I don't know their password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to get the other users password changed, and then login as that person, although this is only appropriate if you're connecting to a domain, using Active Directory etc.

Alternatively, if you are in the local administrators group, or can get yourself added to it, it's quite likely you can connect to the SQL Server instance as yourself with admin rights.

Finally... if you just want access to a particular database, copy the mdf and ldf files, and re-attach them to another instance.